# Simple create charge method returns "Must provide source or customer" error

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

Hin I'm trying to create a charge of a customer example:

```
(async () => {
  try {
    const charge = await stripe.charges.create({
      amount: 2000,
      currency: "usd",
      customer: "cus_NDylKcn97g7OD4",
    });

    console.log("Charge created");
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
})();
```

but this just throws an error:

```
// ...
StripeInvalidRequestError: Must provide source or customer.
```

I'm following the [docs](https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/create?lang=node) and, I see that the required parameter are there in the method, but it just doesn't make it

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Likely that customer doesn't have any [attached payment method](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/attach). You can pass just the customer id as long as that customer has a payment method attached and it's [set as their default](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/update#update_customer-default_source).